# Why was 'Captain' named for 2 different ranks?

Tags: military

"Captain" is named by most Anglophone navies for their [OF-5 rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_(naval)),
[image]

and by their armies for their [OF-2 rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_(armed_forces)) Captain.

[image]

Pictured at the top are 2 US Navy, 1 RNZ, and RAN [Jennifer Wittwer](https://news.navy.gov.au/en/Mar2014/People/896/Naval-Officer-leads-the-way-for-women-peace-and-security-in-Afghanistan.htm)  Captains. Then [CPT Tania Donovan, US Army](https://www.jennmcintyreportraits.com/blog/2018/1/5/military-women-project-cpt-tania-donovan-us-army), Prince Harry, and a RNZ Army Captain.

1. What caused did the same noun "Captain" to be named for two wholly different ranks?
2. Wasn't this ambiguity blindingly obvious? Isn't it obviously, avoidably, and unproductively confusing to use the same noun for two different ranks appears so obviously, avoidably, and unproductively confusing?
3. Why wasn't another noun picked for either OF-2 or OF-5?

Comment: Yeah, I'm always confused about the title of the name which each countries use in different ways.

Comment: Did you look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_(armed_forces))?  "_The term ultimately goes back to Late Latin capitaneus meaning "chief, prominent"; in Middle English adopted as capitayn in the 14th century, from Old French capitaine_ ...".

Comment: @sempaiscuba Non non non. That doesn't explain the OP's question wholly.

Comment: @Kentaro Did you read the rest of that paragraph?  The article even explains the origin of the rank _Group Captain_ in the RAF.

Comment: @sempaiscuba I'm going to make an answer. Then please give me an advice.

Comment: @Kentaro My advice, generally, would be not to answer off-topic questions.

Comment: @sempaiscuba   Ugh, a native speaker already made an answer. I lost :). Yeah, actually as you say, this question is off topic.

Comment: @Kentaro Yep.  But this is a community-moderated site, so I can only advise based on my reading of the rules.  The community may feel differently, and the rep system on SE often encourages people to answer questions that perhaps should simply be closed.  We live in an imperfect Universe. :)

Comment: @sempaiscuba Actually, the American army or navy inherited the British army / navy titles, this question might not be off topic. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Because the army is not the navy, and never the twain shall meet - except in an annual football game, if you're American :-)

Comment: I've heard stories of enlisted men getting called up by captains with demands having developed a technique of politely inquiring what branch they serve in before ... er .. deciding if they need to continue being polite.

Comment: Oh was this question closed? IMO, without historical context there wouldn't be the difference of the title of the army/navy of the same position. I voted to reopen. (Though I think it will not be reopened.)

Comment: @Kentaro: While on the face of it the Wikipedia entry seems to address the question, it is my belief that is a very superficial covering of a complex topic. My answer addresses  several additional aspects of why a relatively small *company-sized* unit is historically the appropriate unit size to be headed by a *chief or prominent person*, while a substantially larger *ship-of-the-line* is the naval equivalent. Thus I believe this question is on topic and should be reopened. I look forward to reading additional answers.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens Thanks for your message. I am quite sorry I lost the race lmao. Before saying something, I think I need to read your answer carefully because I don't understand parts of your answer myself --.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A couple of reasons:

1. The etymology of *captain* - from Late Latin, Old French and Middle English as "*chief, prominent*" - is imminently suited to the rank commanding the basic maneuver units on both sea and land - respectively a ship or a company of ~150 men. Note that while today the maneuver unit is  usually much smaller than a company, that is only true since the First World War. Prior to that time units maneuvred *in the large*, deployed as battalions but maneuvrering as companies.

   As noted in a comment, the [German armed forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniforms_and_insignia_of_the_Kriegsmarine#Officer_ranks) has leveraged both Germanic and Romance language roots to derive the distinct ranks of:

   - *Hauptmann*
     An OF-2, NATO equivalent to an British or U.S. *Captain* (army).
   - *Korvettenkapitän*
     An OF-3, NATO equivalent to an British or U.S. naval *Lieutenant Commander* (navy) or *Major* (army).
   - *Fregattenkapitän*
     An OF-4, NATO equivalent to an British or U.S. *Commander* (navy) or *Lieutenant Colonel* (army).
   - *Kapitän zur See*
     An OF-5, NATO equivalent to an British or U.S. *Captain* (navy) or *Colonel* (army).

   Note that etymology for *hauptman*, the German rank equivalent to captain, is "*head man*" - virtually identical to the etymology above for English *captain*. The main *Romance languages* of French, Spanish and Italian all also use a derivation from Late Latin "*capitaneus*". This speaks to the language-independent nature of the unit size commanded by an army captain being in some sense *fundamental*.

   Likewise, when the [*New Model Army*](http://bcw-project.org/military/new-model-army) was formed by parliament in 1645 it's general officers were, in descending authority:

   - [Captain General](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_general#Great_Britain) Sir Thomas Fairfax;
   - Lieutenant General (of Horse) Oliver Cromwell;
   - Major-General (of Foot) Philip Skippon
   - Lieutenant General (of Ordnance) Thomas Hammond

   Although out of favour in Great Britain since 1799, this rank and it's literal equivalents in other languages remains common as the rank of a senior [*general officer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_officer). Again, the notion is that the most senior commander at a conceptual level, here strategic, is the *captain* - the *chief*, or *most prominent* commander at that level. Likewise the *captain's* second-in-command is a *lieutenant*, and the third-officer is a *major* (derived from the late-Medieval and Renaissance sense of [*sergeant-major*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sergeant_major#History) as the title of what we now term *chief-of-staff*).
2. The different armed forces branches evolved in near complete independence for centuries, up to perhaps the early 1800's. Further, they do not and never have given a *flying fig* for the traditions of the other branches. Soldiers are superstitious, not withstanding their claims to the contrary, and fundamental traditions will never be changed except under either extreme duress or proof of inadequacy. In this case neither applies.

Further, you have missed that there is a third usage in many navies. While the *rank* of *captain* is equivalent to that of *colonel* in English-speaking armies and is usually reserved to officers commanding capital ships, the *title* of *captain* is held by the commanding officer (or C.O.) of every naval vessel of any size, even when commanded by an officer of lesser rank. Those officers are fully entitled to be addressed as "*Captain*" while aboard and commanding their vessel.

---

Usage of the term [*company* (originally *free company*)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_company) as a team of armed and trained men - led by a *captain*, a *lieutenant*, and various *sergeants* led by a *sergeant-major* - dates back at least to the mercenary troops of the Late Middle Ages and Renaissance. These units were of indeterminate size, the [*Company of the Hat*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Company_of_the_Hat) for example being at least 1300 men at one point; the limit being the leadership and business skills of its *captain*. As they came with their own command structure and were *independent*, i.e. *free to come or go*, it became standard for a commander to think in terms of the *company* as the deployable unit.

In the late 15th century the Swiss [Pike Square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pike_square) company - a 10x10 array of trained pike men - proved the decisive capability of pikes on the battlefield of the time as well as the importance of precision drill. Over the next three centuries independently deployed companies of pikemen were replaced: first by mixed-arms *battle groups* - *battalions* - comprising companies of pikemen, halberdiers, swordsmen, arquebusiers, musketeers, grenadiers and others drilled to complement and support each other; and then by *battalions* comprising companies of slot-bayonet equipped fusiliers.

At each stage of this development the unit size that could best combine effectiveness and maneuvre speed while maintaining the dense concentration of manpower and weapons to repel cavalry was the *company* of roughly 100-200 men. This is not to say that generals deployed *companies* as a tactical unit - just the opposite. It was a *battalion*'s ability to adopt [a wide variety of formations](http://www.napolun.com/mirror/napoleonistyka.atspace.com/infantry_tactics_4.htm) with its (usually) 6 to 8 well-drilled companies that allowed a general to simply deploy battalions, and allow each to manage its own self-preservation and effectiveness:

Common Napoleonic-Era Infantry Battalion Formations

Note how the *company* remains the largest **maneuvrable** *dense grouping* of men in any of these formations. Once whole battalions of companies packed densely together, as in a *closed column*, maneuvering became impossible without loss of order and control.

- **(March) Column**
  A loose order formation of men, as many abreast as the road bed could support and each rank 5 or 6 feet from the next, designed to optimize march speed. Extra distance between each company eased supervision of the men and provided a means for offers and NCO's to switch sides of the roadbed without disturbing the formation.
- **Line**

  The formation in which a battalion expected and planned to give battle -except where the terrain might be so constrained as to force a narrower formation. Most armies formed line in three ranks except the British who formed in four (Not two, as British oversize battalions could not form square fast enough from an extended two-rank line. Only late in a battle, with opposing cavalry mostly *hors du combat*, would the British form two-rank lines to maximize firepower for a *coup de grâce*.)

  [image]
- **(Battle) Column (Specified by Frontage and Interval)**

  [image]

  A *full interval* column can form line to either left or right by a simple wheel of *frontage unit* (whether company or division), and also forms square quickly. In particular a French *Full Interval Column by Division* (upper left in the diagram) formed line to either right or left, or square, in the time for a *Division* (of two companies) to march one interval.
- **Square(s) - Both Hollow and Closed**

  [image]

  The *closed column* could be formed very quickly against enemy cavalry, but unlike the *hollow square* preferred by the French, British and Prussians was effectively immobile.

  [image]

---

Appendix:

- [**Military Studies** by *Marshal Ney*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.279048/page/n7/mode/2up)

  Note that in the French infantry of this time each *company* - the administrative unit - comprised just a single  platoon (*peloton*) as its maneuvre unit. Similarly in the artillery the *battery* was the gun tubes, carriages, limbers, etc. while the men servicing said equipment were a *company* of artillerists. Once the *battery* and *artillery company* had been united, on campaign or maneuvres, the combination might be referred to by either term.
- [**On Skirimishing** by *Général de Divison Morand (1811)*](http://www.demi-brigade.org/tirdaven.htm)

  Note below the emphatic instruction on training the troops by company, rather than to train a small number of men taken from each company.

  > We recognized that it was generally harmful to take a certain number of men by company, for flankers and skirmishers, and that it was preferable to take entire companies.
  >
  > The companies of voltigeurs who are elite companies, cannot always perform this role without serious inconvenience, it has, therefore, appeared appropriate to me that in the case of the companies who could be used for the role, are trained for it.
  >
  > As it is important for the sake of uniformity that there is some method to adopt, I send you, my dear General, a summary of the manoeuvres that I invite you to train the regiments under your orders to do, whether of light infantry or of infantry of line. I want us to benefit from the present season for training the troops.

---

Finally, I believe these answers provide additional useful background on how and why modern infantry ranks and organization came to be.

- **[What should I call bands of armed men in the Middle Ages?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/54083/what-should-i-call-bands-of-armed-men-in-the-middle-ages/54086#54086)**

  Covers a couple of additional points on the origin of a *company* as a body of men led by a *captain*.
- **[What were the ranks in the Army of Imperial Spain?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/38250/what-were-the-ranks-in-the-army-of-imperial-spain/50481#50481)**

  Covers, among other aspects, how the medieval title of *sergeant-major* became the three modern ranks of:

  - *Sergeant-Major*
    A non-commissioned (but usually if not always warranted) rank;
  - *Major*
    A senior commissioned officer rank; and
  - *Major General*
    A two-star general officer rank **below** the three-star rank of *Lieutenant General* even though a *Lieutenant* is usually thought of as less senior than a *Major*.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the "commading the basic maneuver units" part of point 1? I'm really curious on this topic myself, and would like to read up...

Comment: Things were (are?) a little different in the German Navy.I had a cousin who served in in a U-boat until his boat was sunk in 1944, His rank at that time translates into English as Lieutenant Captain (equivalent to Lieutenant Commander). The German Navy at that time had four different ranks with "kapitan" in their title (Kapitänleutnant [my cousin], Korvettenkapitän, Fregattenkapitän, and Kapitän zur See), The last two are Junior Captain and Captain. And you thought the American and British Navy ranks were confusing...

Comment: @T.E.D.: Here is some history.

Comment: Whoa, nice. Hopefully I'll have time to read it later today...

Comment: +1 for a very comprehensive answer. Just a small linguistic nit-pick on behalf of my Scottish, Welsh and Northern Irish compatriots - HM Armed Forces are **British**, not **English** - that just happens to be the official language of the UK. :-)

Comment: @TheHonRose: Thank you - corrected.